# Wi-Fi connection issues on an ASUS N56VJ

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have recently moved to a new apartment and I'm temporarily using my landlord's Wi-Fi with his permission.

The problem is, I have a lot problems connecting to it in my [ASUS N56VJ](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56VJ/specifications/) but my girlfriend's laptop (also an ASUS but from this year and a lower-end [X550L model](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550LDV/specifications/)) connects just fine.

I've attached the router Wi-Fi configuration page hoping that whatever is causing the problem is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you say you have an [ASUS N56VJ](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56VJ/specifications/) and according [to the specs from ASUS](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56VJ/specifications/) it seems your machine can handle 802.11b, 802.11g or 802.11n, correct? And you say your girlfriend’s machine has no problems connecting even though it is a lower end model, right?

Well, I think the issue might be either the type of 802.11n protocol being used on your machine versus your girlfriend’s. Or possibly your girlfriend’s machine is connecting at 802.11g since you did say it is a lower end model.

Looking at the configuration page from the router it seems like it is 802.11n capable, but all of the 802.11n options are set to `auto` or `off`.

I would not recommend mucking with the router settings—just yet—but rather I would see if you can force your [ASUS N56VJ](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56VJ/specifications/) to connect via 802.11g and see what happens. Then if that works—meaning you get a clean connection with 802.11g—then I would look at the router & see what reasonable settings can be adjusted to allow a happy coexistence between 802.11g and 802.11n.

Specifics are hard to say at this point, but if you could provide the exact model number of your girlfriend’s ASUS for comparison, that could help us compare/contrast what is happening.

**EDIT:** The original poster comments that his girlfriend’s machine is a part of the [ASUS X550L](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550LDV/specifications/) line. And checking the specs for networking shows it only supports 802.11b and 802.11g
but not 802.11n.  So that explains it. The [ASUS N56VJ](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56VJ/specifications/) is having problems negotiating 802.11n. So my best recommendation is that the original poster specify 802.11g when connecting to the router. And if their landlord is open to him tweaking the router to maybe disable 802.11n entirely—if that is an option—that’s another tact. But I bet 802.11n problems are the root of this issue.

Comment: I think you are right. This is my girlfriend's asus: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550LDV/specifications/

I'm no sure if that is the exact model, I do know it's the X550L series.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [Comtrend NexusLink Wi-Fi/modem](http://www.comtrend.com/cee/links/21$sndcee.htm) and the Wi-Fi was a little odd with its interpretation of WPA/WPA2 mixed encryption. Try setting the security to either WPA or WPA2 and use an 8 character password. Mine didn't like passwords over 8 characters.

Comment: It's about the laptop wifi and the wifi board in the router - both devices are suspect in this case, so a password change is relevant. The wifi card in girlfriend's laptop is a different model to his according to specs.